# How to properly install a linux package into a Google cloud plateform project?

Tags: python, linux, google-cloud-platform, librosa, sound-recognition

I'm deploying a webapp on Google Cloud Plateform to test some trained models with Fast.ai. One of them is for sound recognition, and I need to use librosa to create a spectogram of the sound provided by the user. But librosa needs **ffmpeg** to work properly.

I added **ffmpeg** to my **Dockerfile**. It works fine when I deploy the application, but after few requests I get this error (as if **ffmpeg** is not installed) :

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/audioread/**init**.py", line 116, in audio_open: raise NoBackendError()
>   at load (/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py:119)

Sometimes, it works again. It looks like it depends on which instance the application is running on.

Here is my Dockefile :

````
FROM python:3.6-slim-stretch

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y python3-dev gcc
RUN apt install -y ffmpeg

ADD requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY app app/

RUN python app/server.py

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["python", "app/server.py", "serve"]```
````

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the followig line to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt install -y libav-tools
```

Comment: This change nothing. It works, and then after few requests I get the same "No Backend Error".

Comment: Oh, OK. This fixes the issue in a non-containerized environment. So it must be something else...